# UNIX: Using egrep or sed to find the line with the first occurrence of a string?

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I am working in a bash shell and I am trying to print only the line of the first occurrence of the string. For example, for the string '`auir`', if I have the file myfile.txt and it contains:

```
123
asdf
4wirajw
forauir somethingelse
starcraft
mylifeforauir
auir
something else
tf.rzauir
```

I want to output "`forauir somethingelse`"

So far, I use the command

```
sed -n '/auir/p' myfile.txt
```

which gives me all the occurrences of this string. How can I only get the first line that '`auir`' occurs on? It'd be great if it was just a single command or pipeline of commands.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: starcraft as example.  awesome.

Comment: Surely you will be looking for "Aiur"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This `sed` command

`sed -n '/auir/p' myfile.txt | head -1`

solves your problem.

Comment: You might as well use a `sed` script which quits after printing the first occurrence; like `sed '/auir/!d;q'`

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! Works! :)

Comment: @tripleee Oh that's imaginative, I'm new to shell stuff, gonna try that out. Thanks!

Comment: @tripleee's answer is much more clever than mine `:(`

Answer (score 18):

Use this:

```
grep -m1 auir myfile.txt
```

Comment: Yeup, grep is alright, beerbjay beat you to it by 2 minutes though, gotta give him the points. Always nice to know multiple ways to do the same thing though. thanks for the response!

Comment: The redirection isn't necessary.

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/auir/!d;q' file
```

or

```
sed -n '/auir/{p;q}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

sed -n  -e   '4s/auir/auir/p' file

Answer (score 1):

Or it can be as simple as this

```
grep auir myFile.txt|head -1
```